# Can regex extract a substring, specifically after another without including the first?

Tags: java, regex

(Edit, I said 'digit', I should have said 'alphanumeric char')

How do I extract a postfix from a string from a list of possibles (`,X`,`,Y`,`,X)`,`),Y`).  All need to be preceded by a alphanumeric character to be valid but the character is not to be extracted:-

What I am using is `\w(,X|,Y|,X\)|\),Y){1}$` but this *includes* the preceding character (`\w`) in the extracted value.

(Unit tests pass but it's not sophisticated enough to test the returned match)
https://regex101.com/r/4Ggu7z/5/tests

Comment: [Does this work better for you?](https://regex101.com/r/4Ggu7z/4)

Comment: Lookbehind is what you are looking for I guess. Try this regex : `(?<=\d)(,X|,Y|,X\)|\),Y)$` (demo : https://regex101.com/r/4Ggu7z/3 )

Comment: It does indeed @anubhava.  Add it as an answer and the acceptance is yours, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer.

You can use a negative lookahead instead of matching character in your regex. Here is working regex:

```
(?<=\w)(,[XY]|,X\)|\),Y)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4Ggu7z/6/tests)